# Significant Quadratic terms - linear regression - R

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

I'm given the following data:

[image]

I'm told to first fit the quadratic model.

[image]

```
 > time = c(10,20,15,11,11,19,11,13,17,18,16,16,17,18,10)
 > experience = c(24,1,10,15,17,3,20,9,3,1,7,9,7,5,20)
 > fit = lm (time ~ experience + I(experience^2))
> summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + I(x^2))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.8287 -0.8300  0.5054  0.7476  1.1713 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 20.091108   0.724705  27.723    3e-12 ***
x           -0.670522   0.154706  -4.334 0.000972 ***
I(x^2)       0.009535   0.006326   1.507 0.157605    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.091 on 12 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9162,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9022 
F-statistic: 65.59 on 2 and 12 DF,  p-value: 3.465e-07
```

Everything seems fine there.

My model is

```
y = 20.091-.671x+.0095x^2
```

Plotting it:

```
> x = seq(0,25, by = .1)
> y = fit$coefficient[1]+fit$coefficient[2]*x+fit$coefficient[3]*x^2
> lines(x,y)
```

[image]

Again, everything seems fine.

But then I'm told to test whether or not the quadratic term is significant at the a = .1 significance level.

So I do

```
> fit1 = lm (time ~ experience + I(experience^2))
> fit2 = lm(time~experience)
> anova(fit2, fit1)

Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: time ~ experience
Model 2: time ~ experience + I(experience^2)
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1     13 16.984                           
2     12 14.280  1    2.7037 2.2719 0.1576
```

So my F value for the quadratic term is 2.27. Corresponding to a probability of .1576. .1576 > .1 therefore the quadratic term is significant at a = .1

But my professor has indicated that we should find the quadratic term to be insignificant to our model. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: this should be moved to stats.stackexchange.com. and your professor is correct

Comment: "significant" means **less than** alpha. So your results are insignificant, just as your professor indicated.

Comment: So what exactly does the value .1576 mean? In plain english

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics: it belongs on CrossValidated


Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are failing to do is construct orthogonal polynomial terms. The poly() function in R is designed for that purpose.

```
 time = c(10,20,15,11,11,19,11,13,17,18,16,16,17,18,10)
 experience = c(24,1,10,15,17,3,20,9,3,1,7,9,7,5,20)
 fit = lm (time ~ poly(experience, degree=2))
 summary(fit)
#--------------
Call:
lm(formula = time ~ poly(experience, degree = 2))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.8287 -0.8300  0.5054  0.7476  1.1713 

Coefficients:
                              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                    14.8000     0.2817  52.544 1.48e-15 ***
poly(experience, degree = 2)1 -12.3861     1.0909 -11.354 8.94e-08 ***
poly(experience, degree = 2)2   1.6443     1.0909   1.507    0.158    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.091 on 12 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9162,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9022 
F-statistic: 65.59 on 2 and 12 DF,  p-value: 3.465e-07
```

Your F statistic is not specific for the quadratic term but is really comparing the null model to the two terms model.

Comment: Using poly(x,2), how would you test the significance of x and x^2 with Lrts, without testing a null model vs a model with both terms?

Comment: You need to explain in more precise language what you mean by "test the significance of x and x^2 with Lrts". You have the F-test whch is a LR test and you have the two t-tests which are Wald-tests. The Wald-test for degree=2 should agree with an anova comparing this model with a one-degree (non-poly) model with x as covariate.